# What is the point of a adafruit data logger

Tags: adafruit, datalogging

In order to play an audio file, I was suggested to get an Adafruit data logger, yet right now I am stuck with the project and I realized that I'm not using the data logger to its full potential.

Yet I am unable to comprehend the purpose of a data logger ; all I'm using it for is to read SD Cards, and I can do that with a SD Card reader. I did read the whole documentation, data sheet, etc, and I can see that it has some cool functions, but my question is still, why data logger?

I know this  might be a stupid question, but I genuinely don't get what the data logger is supposed to be a huge help of. Please help me.

Comment: i don't know either, that doesn't make sense to me. free advice is worth just that sometimes...

Comment: Do you mean the Adafruit Datalogger Shield, or the Adafruit Feather M0 "Adalogger"

Comment: IMHO it have RTC+SD reader+libraries, so with minimal effort (and knowledge) anybody can alling those connectors, copy-paste some invocation and make magic like a real wizard. The Arduino underlaying principle. Or you can read datasheets, write your own code and make such PCB in kitchen yourself and not pay their premium prices (opens with knowledge, tools and experience). Or you could do it yourself, but it would cost you a week of work, so it is cheaper just buy it and fix it to your needs (opens with good job and money). So there are at least 2 groups, who buy it and so Adafruit sells it :)

Comment: > why data logger?... maybe you can ask the guy/guys who suggested it to you? maybe they had some valid reasons? conceptually a data logger is there to log data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-data-logger-shield/overview)?

[image: Adafruit data logger]

That is a shield that has an SD card interface (with appropriate level-shifting for the SD card) plus a real-time clock.

The rest is "prototyping" area for you to install your own devices.

> In order to play an audio file, I was suggested to get an Adafruit data logger

I don't see how this helps play audio files, however you might read the audio file from the SD card. Then you need to send it to a DAC (digital-to-analog converter) to convert the digital information to analogue.

The Adafruit data logger is fine for recording data (for example, temperatures) but I don't see why someone would recommend it for playing audio files (apart from the SD card interface).

> my question is still, why data logger?

Better ask the person that recommended it, eh?